What is the exact time complexity of this algorithm?
I attempted to solve the problem at this HackerRank link (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem?isFullScreen=true) Given a square matrix, calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals., But I wanted to avoid implementing the ( O(n^2) ) algorithm. Instead, I devised the version below. However, I'm curious about its complexity; it appears to be ( O(n) ), but due to the final condition where i is incremented only when j traverses the columns, it might actually be closer to ( O(n^2) ). Could someone please help me understand this?
function diagonalDifference(arr = [[]]) {
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  let mainDiagonal = 0;
  let secondDiagonal = 0;

  const rows = arr[0].length;

  while (i < rows) {
    if (i === j) {
      mainDiagonal += arr[i][j];
    }

    if (j + i === rows - 1) {
      secondDiagonal += arr[i][j];
    }

    if (j === rows - 1) {
      j = 0;
      i++;
    } else {
      j++;
    }
  }

  return Math.abs(mainDiagonal - secondDiagonal);
}

I asked ChatGPT, which indicated the complexity as ( O(n) ), while Codeium suggested ( O(n^2) ).


Add the full problem : links will broke and the question would be incomplete. 2) you go through every cell of the matrix to check if it's part of a diagonal. So you cannot go faster than the number of cells. This is a hint to find the complexity of your algorithm, there may be algorithm that go faster by not checking all cells. 3) For your interest, Generative AI is banned


@AloisChristen here is the problem I was trying to solve.
Given a square matrix, calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.

Just calculate the diagonals one by one. Then you have O(n). What you have now is O(n^2) which is very bad. What you have come up with is just a "tricky" implementation of two nested for loops.

@SupportUkraine Thanks, I'll try this approach right now.

@MárioAlfredoJorge Edit the question to add the problem in the question, so it's complete. Comments are not the best place for edits or additionnal information :)

@AloisChristen I'll do that. Thanks

The complexity is O(n^2).
The code although has only one outer loop the conditions are written such that there is an operation on every matrix cell.
Every time you are reaching the end of one row (by visiting all its cells column by column), then you move to the next row.
You are basically doing an interaction of every column of every row. So if there are 6 rows and columns, you will have 36 operations. Hence O(n^2).
Before looking at the code, visualize what the you tried to do with the code and you will be able to answer yourself better.

Thanks for your explanation, now it's clearer.

Sure. FWIW, the problem can be solved in O(n) but I hope you go around finding your own way for that. You can google it up to get hints.
Please accept/upvote the answer if it helped you

The time of the algorithm is O(n²) where input matrix is nxn. Notice that you execute the body of the loop once for every (i,j) pair of legal indices, effectively traversing the matrix one value at a time. Since there are n² values, well...
There is some confusion since the size of input S is also O(n²), so in input size the complexity is O(S). Nonetheless, it's slow for this task. If you want to do better, you need to skip some cells completely (increasing your indices by more than one in certain cases, for example).
ChatGPT is not the most coherent source of answers. Prompting it to "explain the reasoning behind the answer step by step" is known to produce somewhat better results in similar tasks but they still have an unpleasantly high chance to be hallucinatory.

Thanks for your explanation, now it's clearer.

If we disentangle the code (turn incrementing i and j into equal but more readable syntax) and rewrite it as
...

const rows = arr[0].length;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < rows; ++j) {
    if (i === j)
      mainDiagonal += arr[i][j];

    if (i + j === rows - 1)
      secondDiagonal += arr[i][j];
  }
}

...

We'll easily see that it has O(n^2) time complexity.
We can provide a better - O(n) time complexity - algorithm:
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
  mainDiagonal += arr[i][i];
  secondDiagonal += arr[i][rows - 1 - i];
}

